# multiselect menu moves when i open the console

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng, multi-select

I have a p-multiselect component from primeNg inside a div,at first the menu, when expanded, was being cut by the accordion. We solved the problem using appendTo="body" in the  element. Now the values are shown correctly, the problem is that when i open the console or when i use a mobile device to open the web app the menu from the  component moves to the right/left, but if i remove the appendTo this problem disappear. We tryed with z-index properties as alternative to appendTo but didn't work. How can i solve this?
We are using Angular 8.
[image]

[image]

EDIT: the first image is when the console is close, the second one is when the console is open (if you read above i wrote the exact opposite case, this is because at first we tried to solve this aligning the left margin, in these picture we are not aligning the margin).
Below i added the html code we used.

[image]

Comment: Any screen capture or Stackblitz?

Comment: i edited the question adding the screen capture of the problem and the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the solution 1 week later i posted this question. We solved this problem defining an attribute inside a div (the outermost) and, in the multiselect, we used appendTo with the attribute we defined in the outer div. This solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, I'm also facing this issue on `p-dropdown` via `Angular10`;

When you inspect to html. `left` position of the panel is a bit shift that cause by resizing of the screen.

**The solution**

1. **style.scss** - is one this a must, or you need `::ng-deep` if you paste this class on other `.scss` file

   ```
   .force-left {
     left: 0 !important;
   }
   ```
2. **.component.ts**

   ```
   <p-multiselect
   ...
     panelStyleClass="force-left"
   ...
   ></p-dropdown>
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it's not working: with left : 0 !important; we have the menù on the left of the whole page, not on aligned with the border of the parent element. If we change left with right, the menu start from the left border of the parent div and ends at the right border of the page